# The find-lisp-object-file-name return wrong value

Tags: elisp

I'm using Emacs 26.1, and recently I found the `find-lisp-object-file-name` always return `nil` when I call it in following ways:

```
(find-lisp-object-file-name 'call-process nil)
;;=> nil

(find-lisp-object-file-name 'call-process 'defun)
;;=> nil
```

However, when I use the `describe-function` to show information about `call-process`, it shows the `call-process` is from "C source code".  It looks like the function `find-lisp-object-file-name` is not reliable.

More examples:

```
(find-lisp-object-file-name 'cond nil)
;;=> nil *WRONG* 

(find-lisp-object-file-name 'cdr nil)
;;=> nil  *WRONG*

(find-lisp-object-file-name 'user-full-name nil)
;;=> "src/editfns.c"   *CORRECT*
```

The question: how can I **always** get the correct file name information of a symbol?